# General strategies for solving functional equations.

Tags: problem-solving, functional-equations, advice

I am very bad at solving functional equations, though I enjoy them a lot, so I'm looking for some strategies to solve functional equations. Like what are some approaches we would try to start solving a functional equation. I'm a high school student so I don't learn functional equations at school, I'm just learning them for olympiads.

Comment: Well I wonder why this question got no answers . It's a really negative thing about the community tbh . 'cause whenever they see the exact same question they easily put a label of duplicate but when such good questions get ignored for such a long time , they do nothing except liking it . In case the user make some mistake in asking questions, the seniors say their time got wasted , but what if questions get ignored for 2+years ? Isn't it a waste of time for the asker ?